# Editing Mode Alt+MMB Keymap Name

Tags: edit-mode, customization, keymap

Blender has a feature to rotate/orbit the viewport while editing an object in the edit mode which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> click-drag. I want to change it to an <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd>.

[image]

However, I couldn't find the Keymap name for that setting in the Preferences/Keymap. Is there anyone who knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

Typing 'view3d.view_axis' (without the quotes) into the <kbd>Name</kbd> search under <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap</kbd> should find it.

[image]